# Chrome + css3: media query zoom bug

Tags: css, google-chrome, media-queries, responsive-design

A very nice feature of building a percentage width site with media queries is that when you zoom in, the site will always be 100% of the viewport, respecting the media queries even on zoom.

Please see http://pastebin.com/ige96Czv for the full CSS file (it is actually a .less file)

and https://s140452.gridserver.com/locations/

for the test site.

The zoom effect that i described above works great in Firefox and Safari, but on Chrome the media queries do not register on zoom.

Does anyone know why? Is this a Chrome bug, or is something wrong in my code?

Comment: Wish they'd fix this. It makes perfect sense for the queries to work with zoom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bug is explained in more detail here:

http://alastairc.ac/2012/01/zooming-bug-in-webkit/